# replacing commas with slashes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace `,` with `/` in JavaScript and wrote the code below. There are multiple text boxes available in the form. I want to write a single function and call them on all the text fields.

The issue that I am experiencing is that I am not able to send the current ID to the JavaScript method. How is this properly done?

```
function removeComma(val) {
  var values = document.getElementById('val').value;   //Object Required Error
  var n=values.replace(/,/, "/"); 
  document.getElementById('val').value=n;
}

<input type="text" id="one" name="one" onkeypress="removeComma(this)">
<input type="text" id="two" name="two" onkeypress="removeComma(this)">
<input type="text" id="three" name="three" onkeypress="removeComma(this)">
```

The error that I am getting from above code is `OBJECT REQUIRED` at first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be...

```
document.getElementById(val).value
```

... instead, as you're probably going to call this function for each input textbox separately, sending their ids as params into the function.

**UPDATE:** ... and your edit clearly shows even that's not the case: you're passing an *element* itself into a function. That's good, but then you don't have to look after that element with `document.getElementById` - you already have it.

Still, there're another issue here: if you need to replace all commas, you need to add `/g` modifier to that regex. Otherwise multiple commas (added by copy-pasting, for example) won't be replaced.

Overall, I'd rewrite it like this:

```
function removeComma(el) {
  el.value = el.value.replace(/,/g, '/');
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hvfGV/) to play with (and here's its [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/SMkCr/) working with [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.oninput) handlers instead - in my opinion, the latter is smoother).

Comment: it is already there.  var values = document.getElementById('val').value

Comment: `'val'` is a _string_. `val` is an expression - evaluating to a value of a variable named `val`. In this example using string literals has no point whatsoever.

Comment: @raina77ow's fiddle is the most reusable method.  global flag is an important addition.

Comment: @raina77ow Thank you very much for your description. It helped me to learn something new. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you, riana77ow. I needed this for our image upload script. It is a dynamic form, and it separates each entry with a comma. So, if I have a comma in the title of the image, it will break that entry into multiple database records. Using your function, I was able to quickly replace the comma with a slash while typing without the need to edit all instances of the comma. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're passing the clicked element to your function, hence you don't need `document.getElementById()` at all. This fixes your problem.

```
function removeComma(val) {
    var values = val.value;
    var n=values.replace(/,/g, "/"); 
    val.value=n;
}
```

Notice also, that `onkeypress` is fired *before* the value of the `input` element is changed. You can use `onkeyup` or rather `oninput` if you want to use the last updated value of `input`.

If you really have to use the `id` of the element, you need to pass it in the argument:

```
<input type="text" id="one" name="one" onkeypress="removeComma(this.id)">
```

And then also remove the quotes around `val`:

```
var values = document.getElementById(val).value;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('val')
```

should be

```
document.getElementById('one')
```

If you make this change you don't need to send this to *removeComma*.

If you keep *this* then use the following function

```
function removeComma(val) {
    var values = val.value;
    var n=values.replace(/,/, "/"); 
    val.value=n;
}
```

Comment: It works for one input. I want to pass the ID as parameter. If I have multiple input, then how to use the same function for multiple inputs.

Comment: Nice copy-paste from Teemu's answer.

Comment: :D Do I really have to say that it wasn't copy/paste. I just replace *document.getElementById('val')* with *val*.